# Show content between two dates with PHP?

Tags: php

I want to be able to show some content or echo some text between and on two dates.

Its for a promotion of a product, between the dates given the price will be lower and after the promotion the price will return to the original cost.

Is this possible?

Cheers

Matt

Comment: Content from what, from where? Where does the price come from? What specific problem do you have in implementing this?

Comment: I'm not sure which direction to take, kind of confused myself. Basically the first date is a $variable and so is the second date. I need help with php to check to see if todays date is between the two set dates as mentioned. If so to echo some text.

Comment: The promotion for example, will say between Monday and Friday next week the price of so and so will be $5.00, with php, when the promotion starts it will do something. Hope i made this clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$current_time = time();
if($current_time > $start_time && $current_time < $end_time){
    // Whatever you want during the time interval
}else{
    // Whatever you want outside the time interval
}
```